# ftp_nb_fput not transferring more than 4096 bytes

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a file to a server with ftp_nb_fput, just that it doesn't upload more than 4096 bytes from the files, and the file has about 700 kb.

```
$connection_to = ftp_connect($host_to);
$ftp_to = ftp_login($connection_to, $user_to, $pass_to);
$fp = fopen($directory_to_move_files.$file_to_move, 'r');
ftp_nb_fput($connection_to, $file_to_move, $fp,  FTP_ASCII);
ftp_close($connection_to);
```

I am interested to use this function not file_put_contents or CURL.
There is no error that I get.

Comment: are you in a local enviroment or hosting ? and what version of php, and for last is it on a windows system or linux ?

Comment: @DiegoCoderPlus hosting enviroment (dedicated) site5 to be exact, PHP 5.3, LINUX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to take into considertion when working with ftp_nb_put function from ftp

1. it works asynchronously so it works using chunks it meaning that

   ftp_nb_put($my_connection, "test.remote", "test.local", FTP_BINARY);

will only result in a small chunk of data uploaded and the flag `FTP_MOREDATA` returned from the ftp_nb_put function arises, so to complete the upload using this command you will need to iterate:

```
$ret = ftp_nb_put($my_connection, "test.remote", "test.local", FTP_BINARY);
while ($ret == FTP_MOREDATA) {
   $ret = ftp_nb_continue($my_connection);
}
```

2. there are the following directives to take into account so you can upload files with big size, this directives are located in `php.ini` and can not be modified from current script:

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = XXM

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = XXM

where XX are the number of Mb. do not forget to put M,
After any Modification it will be neccesary to restart server.

Comment: those are 32 M, and the files are 700 kb.so is not because of this.

Comment: My guess is that you have a blocking directive by site5, have you tried talking to them, i am pretty sure that if i try your code in a local env it will work just fine, any news please add, I want to know ;-)

Comment: hey wait a minute @user3467855, you are not looping while MORE_DATA flag is present ? .. if not , that is your prob.... you should add $ret = ftp_nb_put($my_connection, "test.remote", "test.local", 
                      FTP_BINARY, ftp_size("test.remote"));
// O: $ret = ftp_nb_put($my_connection, "test.remote", "test.local", 
//                           FTP_BINARY, FTP_AUTORESUME);

while ($ret == FTP_MOREDATA) {
   
   // Haga lo que quiera
   echo ".";

   // Continuar la carga...
   $ret = ftp_nb_continue($my_connection);
}

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transfer the whole file at once, use `ftp_put()`, not `ftp_nb_fput()`. It'll make your code a bit simpler:

```
$connection_to = ftp_connect($host_to);
$ftp_to = ftp_login($connection_to, $user_to, $pass_to);
$local_file = $directory_to_move_files . $file_to_move;
ftp_put($connection_to, $file_to_move, $local_file,  FTP_BINARY);
ftp_close($connection_to);
```

Side note: don't use `FTP_ASCII` unless you're **absolutely** sure the file you're transferring is plain text. It will corrupt binary files, including images. Using `FTP_BINARY` is always safe.

Comment: with `ftp_put` I get error like `Warning failed to open stream, no such file or folder on line....`

Comment: Make sure that the path that you're ending up with in `$local_file` is correct? You haven't included any of the code that generates that path, so I can't tell if that'd be right.